# Get child categories of custom taxonomy category?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I am using custom `post type : portfolio` and have taxonomy for that `portfolio_category`.
I need to get sub categories for a particular category using the above custom taxonomy.

In short, How can I get the child categories for `taxonomy=portfolio_category&tag_ID=80&post_type=portfolio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to get the child terms of a given term. You need to feed the specific term id to either

> - **`parent`**
>
> (integer) Get direct children of this term (only terms whose explicit parent is this value). If 0 is passed, only top-level terms are returned. Default is an empty string.

**OR**

> - **`child_of`**
>
> - (integer) Get all descendents of this term. Default is 0. Note: the difference between child_of and parent is that where parentonly gets direct children of the parent term (ie: 1 level down), child_of gets all descendants (as many levels as are available)

### EXAMPLE:

Get all descendants of term ID 80

(*Requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
$terms = get_terms( 'portfolio_category', ['child_of' => 80] );
```

For only first level children, change `child_of` to `parent`

Comment: Thank you for the help.!But am getting only first child by this code. $terms = get_terms('portfolio_category',  array("child_of" => 80));

Comment: `child_of` gets **all** children from a given term, in this case term `80`. If there is more, and they are not shown, then it means that the terms that does not show is empty, ie, they don't have posts.

Comment: @PieterGoosen is there a way to list the child even if there are no posts in existence?